# Reset Sessions on User Sign-up Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

Ive read plenty of questions asking this exact question, but havent gotten a great answer.

Right now a user goes to the site, and enters their email in.  After they click submit I would like to clear their session/log them out so that they could enter in another email address, so it will save to the DB.

My hacky solution was to call the reset session in my user controller after a user was saved.  This did not work.

I then proceeded to call the sign_out method provided via devise on user save, but that did not work.

Does anyone have any thoughts/solutions?

user_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)


    #if @user.save
      #reset_session
      #sign_out :user
      #flash: 'User was successfully created.'
      #User.find(user_params).forget_me!
    #else
      #render action: 'new'
    #end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using the following code

`reset_session

@current_user = nil`

Comment: Where did you put it?